# Oracle IF/ELSE statement

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

I'm writing a procedure in Oracle12c using Oracle SQL Developer.  What I need to do is check a table to see if a record exists.  If it does, then I need to edit it.  If not, then I need to add it.

So, my "pseudocode" logic would look something like this:

```
If (Select * from MyTable where MyValue = 0) has more than one record, then
  This will be an EDIT line of code
else
  This will be an ADD line of code
end
```

How would I write that in Oracle SQL Developer?

**EDIT:**

Currently my code looks like this, I need to add a piece to update the record.  If Line_ID exists, I need to update the record.  If not, I need to add it.

```
create or replace PROCEDURE CST_WRITE_FEEDBACK (
v_AuditID IN NUMBER,
v_BenefitID IN NUMBER,
v_Network1 IN VarChar,
v_Network2 IN VarChar,
v_Network3 IN VarChar,
v_Network4 IN VarChar,
v_Issue1 IN NUMBER,
v_Issue2 IN NUMBER,
v_Issue3 IN NUMBER,
v_Issue4 IN NUMBER,
v_Resolution1 IN NUMBER,
v_Resolution2 IN NUMBER,
v_Resolution3 IN NUMBER,
v_Resolution4 IN NUMBER,
v_Status IN NUMBER,
v_Comment IN VarChar,
v_LineID IN NUMBER,
v_EmpID IN NUMBER
)
AS 
BEGIN

IF 

  INSERT INTO F_AUDIT_LINE ("AUDIT_ID", "BENEFIT_ID", "NETWORK", "NETWORK2", "NETWORK3", "NETWORK4", 
  "ISSUE_ID", "ISSUE_ID2", "ISSUE_ID3", "ISSUE_ID4",
  "RESOLUTION_ID", "RESOLUTION_ID2", "RESOLUTION_ID3", "RESOLUTION_ID4", 
  "LINE_STATUS")
  VALUES (v_AuditID, v_BenefitID, v_Network1, v_Network2, v_Network3, v_Network4,
  v_Issue1, v_Issue2, v_Issue3, v_Issue4,
  v_Resolution1, v_Resolution2, v_Resolution3, v_Resolution4,
  v_Status
  );

END CST_WRITE_FEEDBACK;
```

Comment: Just use Merge function on Oracle

Comment: Can you expand on this?

Comment: I've removed tag for SQL Developer as code not depends on editor you use.

Comment: @kacper - perhaps (or even "likely") that is true in this case, but not in general. There **are** things that depend on the editor. For example, in Oracle 12c there is `MATCH_RECOGNIZE`, and in the `PATTERN` clause you may use reluctant matching (things like `*?` or `+?`). Those will not work properly in SQL Developer because it's written in Java, the ? is not part of a string, and so the ? will be interpreted as a Java variable placeholder - you'll get errors on perfectly valid code. It's a shame that we need to know about such nonsense, but we do.

Comment: @mathguy I'm sensing some bitterness there! *{;-)

Comment: @JohnnyBones..The answer provided is very clear and is what you need. Just follow that and am sure you will do it yourself.

Comment: @Boneist - yes, that is correct. Pointed in Oracle's direction, of course - not Kacper's.

Comment: @mathguy I had assumed so! *{;-)

Answer (score 5):

```
declare
  i number;
begin
  Select count(*) into i from MyTable where MyValue = 0;
If (i > 0)  then
  update ...
else
  insert ...
end;
/
```

But as mentioned in comment you can have it by:

```
merge into MyTable m
using (select v_AuditID, v_BenefitID, v_Network1, v_Network2, _Network3, _Network4, 
              v_Issue1, v_Issue2, v_Issue3, v_Issue4, 
              v_Resolution1, v_Resolution2, v_Resolution3, v_Resolution4, v_Status 
       from dual) d
on (d.MyValue = m.Myvalue)
when matched then 
  update set ..
when not matched then 
  insert ...
```

If you provide code of your procedure we can expand for you commands.

Comment: @JohnnyBones This isn't a code writing service for you. In addition to Kacper's answer, there's plenty of useful information about merge out there on the internet, such as [here](https://oracle-base.com/articles/9i/merge-statement). Why not give writing your own merge statement a go, and then asking for help if you get stuck?

Comment: @Boneist - Did you look at my profile before writing this?

Comment: @JohnnyBones - I am missing your point. If anything, that makes Boneist's remarks even more valid. `MERGE` is in the SQL standard, it is not a proprietary Oracle thing. And it is EXACTLY what is needed to either update or insert, depending on whether a row exists or it doesn't. And it's very easy to understand - very intuitive syntax. So I agree 100% with Boneist and have the same questions for you, even more so after you pointed me/us to your profile.

Comment: @mathguy - OK, I have zero to limited experience with Oracle.  It's my understanding (and I've been here for quite some time) that this site was designed to be the *de facto* question and answer site, and my hours on Meta tells me that answers should be complete and thorough.  Considering my lack of Oracle, I can't see how telling me to look up *MERGE* is either complete or thorough, especially when I've posted my entire block of code.

Comment: @JohnnyBones - On your profile you call yourself a SQL Server **master**. In most contexts that means knowledgeable, experienced, a "guru". SQL Server has the `MERGE` statement, and although I don't know SQL Server at all, I asume it implements the SQL Standard syntax (just the same as Oracle does). So I don't see how *limited experience with Oracle* is relevant. This is why in my comment I explicitly said `MERGE` is not an Oracle thing. Unless you mean something unusual by **master**.  And no, SO (in my limited experience) is not a "complete and thorough" (and free) code-writing service.

Comment: @mathguy - Please read the [first quoted paragraph here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254770/what-is-stack-overflow-s-goal).  Perhaps you need to understand the site's purpose a little better before answering/commenting?

Comment: @JohnnyBones You asked a question to which the answer was "use a merge statement". You were even given an example of what that might look like. Most people would see that as a complete answer and they'd go off and research how to apply that answer to their own situation. For someone who is a self-declared master, I'm surprised you expected to be spoon-fed the exact answer to your situation rather than taking the opportunity to learn more about a new-to-you concept and how to apply it to your situation.

Comment: Mom always told me not to expect everyone to be [as thorough as I am](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38308854/have-autonumbered-column-restart-value-from-1-after-primary-key-value-changes/38309125#38309125)...  Oh well, I got it working so I guess I'm done here anyway.